# Clipping polygon based on a line to get a polygon in R

Tags: raster, r, polygon, line, sf

I would like to clip a polygon on the right-hand side of a line i.e. the portion of the polygon to the east of the line such that the result is a polygon.
I have tried functions such as `sf::st_intersection`, `sf::st_crop`, but these don't return the desired results.

How can I do this in R?

Please note that in actuality the polygon is a multipolygon i.e. a polygon containing different cities.

Code

```
library(sf)
library(raster)

# Create dummy poly and line for the question using the raster package
plot.new()
A = drawPoly(sp=TRUE, col='red', lwd=2)
B = drawLine(sp=TRUE, col='black', lwd=2)

# Convert to sf
A = st_as_sf(A)
B = st_as_sf(B)

# Clip the poly on the right-hand side of the line such that the result is a polygon.
# Stuck...
```

Purpose

[image]

Desired output

[image]

Comment: When you say "right hand side" do you mean with North up (ie the polygon East of the line) , or do you mean in relation to the start and end point of the line? What about a line that's mostly E-W to start with?

Comment: @Spacedman, yes you are right by "right hand side" I mean the polygon to the east of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A nice approach to using a line to split a polygon is `lwgeom::st_split()`

consider this piece of code, using the well known & much loved North Carolina shapefile that ships with {sf}.

I have introduced two assumptions:

- the line used as blade has to extend over the bounding box of your polygon (idk... if this holds in your use case)
- the line used as blade must not be a parallel (i.e there must be a clear "east" and "west" side; this seems reasoneable)

Assuming these two are met you can use this piece of code (slightly expanded over my earlier answer); what the code does is it splits the bounding box of your polygon, and then makes an intersection of  your polygon (I expect it to work for multipolygons just as well) and the eastern part of the split bounding box.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
    
# included with sf package
shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  summarise() # a single polygon 
    
# a blade to split the polygon
blade <- st_linestring(matrix(c(-93, 32, -75, 37), 
                                   nrow = 2, byrow = T), 
                            dim = "XY") %>% 
  st_sfc(crs = 4326)

plot(shape)
plot(blade, col = "red", add = T)
```

[image]

```
# split bounding box by the blade
bbox_splitted <- shape %>% 
  st_bbox() %>% 
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  lwgeom::st_split(blade) %>% 
  st_collection_extract("POLYGON") %>% 
  st_as_sf() %>% 
  # calculate x coordinate of the centroid; east will be higher
  mutate(xpos = st_coordinates(st_centroid(.))[,"X"]) %>% 
  mutate(position = ifelse(xpos == max(xpos), "east", "west"))

# now a simple intersection with the east part of split bbox
final_result <- bbox_splitted %>% 
  filter(position == "east") %>% 
  st_intersection(shape) %>% 
  st_geometry() # get rid of unnecessary columns

plot(final_result, col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: If you take the centroid of the parts divided by a perfect N-S line then the centroid of the part on the "right" must be more easterly than the centroid of the part on the left. This isn't true for a wobbly line with a vague northerly direction though.

Comment: Jindra, please see my updated questiion, which I hope makes some sense now. Thus, you might have to modify your answer accordingly.