# Add a point to an existing (multi)linestring

Tags: r, sf, st-split

This question is related to [this one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/426506/clipping-polygon-based-on-a-line-to-get-a-polygon-in-r).

I want to clip a polygon to a line, but that line doesn't fully bisect my polygon. If I could add another point to the line, the `lwgeos::st_split()` function should work as intended.

How can I add a point to an existing line/multilinestring to extend it?

For example, following the post above:

```
nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) %>%
  summarise()

broken.blade <- st_linestring(matrix(c(-80, 35.5, -75, 37), 
                     nrow = 2, byrow = T), 
              dim = "XY") %>% 
  st_sfc(crs = 4326)


point.to.add <- st_point(c(-82, 34.5)) %>%
  st_sfc(crs = 4326)

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = nc)+
  geom_sf(data = broken.blade)+
  geom_sf(data = point.to.add)

# The final line should be 
final.line <- st_linestring(matrix((c(-80, 35.5, -75, 37, -82, 34.5) 
                     nrow = 3, byrow = T), 
              dim = "XY")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you need, but here is my naive take on this basically extending your LINESTRING using a linear model up to the boundary box of the POLYGON you want to clip in order to effectively add another POINT to your existing LINESTRING.

Maybe worth noting that this also shortens the existing LINESTRING in case it falls outside of the POLYGON - but this should not really matter if this is about clipping only, in my opinion.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# using your data
nc <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf")) |> summarise()


broken.blade <- st_linestring(matrix(c(-80, 35.5, -75, 37), 
                                     nrow = 2, 
                                     byrow = TRUE), dim = "XY") |> 
  st_sfc(crs = "epsg:4326")

point.to.add <- st_point(c(-82, 34.5)) |>  st_sfc(crs = "epsg:4326")
```

```r
# wrapping the code
st_line_extend <- function(line, poly) {
  
  # extract some data, use same crs
  crs <- st_crs(poly)
  
  bbox <- st_bbox(poly)
  
  line <- st_transform(line, crs = crs)
  
  # extract coordinates from line for linear model
  coords <- st_coordinates(line) |> as.data.frame()
  
  fit <- lm(Y ~ X, data = coords)
  
  # estimate coordinates of line extension intersecting the bbox of poly
  p1x <- bbox[["xmin"]] |> as.numeric()
  
  p1y <- predict(fit, data.frame("X" = p1x)) 
  
  p2x <- bbox[["xmax"]] |> as.numeric()
  
  p2y <- predict(fit, data.frame("X" = p2x)) 
  
  # cast them to points
  p_bbox <- matrix(c(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y), 
                   nrow = 2, 
                   byrow = TRUE) |> 
    st_multipoint() |> 
    st_sfc(crs = crs) |> 
    st_cast("POINT")
  
  # determine the node of your broken line falling inside poly
  p_line <- st_cast(line, "POINT")
  
  p_line_inside <- st_intersection(p_line, poly)
  
  # create a new line merging the bbox points with the inside-poly-point
  result <- c(p_bbox, p_line_inside) |> 
    st_combine() |> 
    st_cast("LINESTRING")
  
  result
}
```

And this is how the result looks like in the end:

```r
final.line <- st_line_extend(broken.blade, nc)


ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  geom_sf(data = broken.blade, col = "green", lwd = 2) + 
  geom_sf(data = final.line, col = "red", lty = 2)
```

[image]

**Edit:**

Let me provide an alternative solution then, modifying the upper approach and simply appending or prepending a given point geometry to an existing line geometry.

Since I was not sure how I could check for "digitizing direction" automatically and I did not want to destroy geometry simply by sorting nodes by X or Y, I solved this using an additional `append` parameter, which you can alter in order to make your point the first or last node of the line:

```r
# alternative approach
st_line_extend2 <- function(line, point, append = TRUE) {
  
  # cast line to point
  points <- st_cast(line, "POINT")
   
  if (append) {
    
    # append point to line nodes
    result <- c(points, point) |> 
      st_combine() |> 
      st_cast("LINESTRING")
    
  } else {
    
    # prepend point to line nodes
    result <- c(point, points) |> 
      st_combine() |> 
      st_cast("LINESTRING")
  }
  
  result
}
```

```r
final.line <- st_line_extend2(broken.blade, point.to.add, append = FALSE)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) +
  geom_sf(data = broken.blade, col = "green", lwd = 2) + 
  geom_sf(data = final.line, col = "red", lty = 2) +
  geom_sf(data = point.to.add)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dimfalk ! This is a very creative solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite solve the problem that I have. My actual use case is a complex polygon (a state boundary) that I need to clip to a complex multilinestring (a river). The river extent is just short of the state boundary, so `st_split` fails. Your approximation works, but doesn't clip the state polygon to the river line. If I could just add a point to continue the river outside of the state boundary, I could properly clip the state boundary.

Comment: @AlexKrohn: I almost suspected something like this... ;-) Yeah, linear modeling would not really work based on complex geometries. Maybe st_line_extend2(), being much simpler, is what you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the line (river) over the boundary, I will take 2 last points of river and calculate the angle (azimuth) between them. It will serve as rotation angle for other (outside boundary) point:

Data prep using OpenStreetMap for state area and river. In reality the river crosses the area, however I'm using negative buffer to cut it before boundary.

```r
bb <- osmdata::getbb("województwo dolnośląskie")

b <- osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25*60) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "name", value = "województwo dolnośląskie") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf() |>
  osmdata::unname_osmdata_sf()
#> Loading required namespace: sf

border <- b$osm_multipolygons |>
  sf::st_transform(crs = "EPSG:2180")

o <- osmdata::opq(bb, timeout = 25*60) |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "waterway", value = "river") |>
  osmdata::add_osm_feature(key = "name", value = "Odra") |>
  osmdata::osmdata_sf() |>
  osmdata::unname_osmdata_sf()

river <- o$osm_multilines[1, , ] |>
  sf::st_transform(crs= "EPSG:2180")

tmap::tm_shape(border) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_shape(river) +
  tmap::tm_lines()
```

[image]

```r
river_short = sf::st_intersection(river, sf::st_buffer(border, dist = -1000))

zoom <- sf::st_bbox(c(xmin = 285000, xmax = 290000, ymin = 430000, ymax = 435000), crs = "EPSG:2180")

tmap::tm_shape(border, bbox = zoom) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_shape(river_short) +
  tmap::tm_lines()
```

[image]

Let's take last 2 points of our river (multilinestring), which serve the basis for angle calculation and new point distance

```r
p <- river_short |>
  subset(select = c(name, geometry)) |>
  sf::st_cast(to = "POINT") |>
  tail(2)

p
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 286959.8 ymin: 432203.6 xmax: 286960.8 ymax: 432312.2
#> Projected CRS: ETRF2000-PL / CS92
#>        name                  geometry
#> NA.827 <NA> POINT (286960.8 432203.6)
#> NA.828 <NA> POINT (286959.8 432312.2)
```

Please note the X coordinates of both points, the difference is just 1 m, so the line will be almost vertical (in fact, alpha is -0.01 rad). Let's calculate the angle and coordinates of new point. The distance (2000 m) is taken arbitrary, you can estimate yours or calculate shortest distance between river end and your polygon, then multiply it x2 or x3.

```r
alpha <- atan(
  (sf::st_coordinates(p[2, ,])[1] - sf::st_coordinates(p[1, ,])[1]) / (sf::st_coordinates(p[2, ,])[2] - sf::st_coordinates(p[1, ,])[2])
)

x1 <- 2000 * sin(alpha)
y1 <- 2000 * cos(alpha)

new_point <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_geometry(p[1, , ]) + c(x1, y1), crs = "EPSG:2180")

l <- sf::st_cast(sf::st_union(p[2, ,], new_point), "LINESTRING") 

tmap::tm_shape(border, bbox = zoom) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_shape(river_short) +
  tmap::tm_lines() +
  tmap::tm_shape(new_point) +
  tmap::tm_dots(size = 1) +
  tmap::tm_shape(l) +
  tmap::tm_lines(col = "green", lty = 2, lwd = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-31 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>